# Apple Maps Web Snapshots API works only intermittently

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, apple-maps

I'm trying to use Apple's Maps Web Snapshots:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/snapshots

I've got a bit of PHP code that I'm using to generate the required signature.

```
<?php

$params = array();
if (isset($_GET["center"])) {
    $params[] = "center=" . $_GET["center"];
}
$params[] = "size=640x640";
$params[] = "scale=2";
$params[] = "teamId=<my team ID here>";
$params[] = "keyId=<my maps key here>";

$data = "/api/v1/snapshot?" . implode("&", $params);

$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://<my private key file here>.p8");

$signature = '';
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid, 'sha256');

$url = ("https://snapshot.apple-mapkit.com" . $data . "&signature=" . base64_encode($signature));

openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
```

The weird behavior is this...

Typically, the resulting URL will return this:

```
{"error":{"message":"Not Authorized","details":[]}}
```

However, if I generate a few more URLs, with the *exact same data* (resulting in slightly different signatures each time), *those URLs won't work either*.

But, eventually, if I try a few more times, eventually *one of the URLs **will work,** and return the PNG snapshot.*

What's even weirder - *after I find a URL that works, **all the earlier URLs, which earlier returns errors, now also work!***

So, I don't think it's necessarily a bug in the code, because, after a half-dozen or so trials, it will inevitably work.

I thought it might be something odd about the openssl_sign method, but I can reproduce this exact same behavior with a JavaScript signing implementation, using https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/index.html.

Essentially, the API seems to only work for 1 out of every 5-6 signed requests, which renders it pretty unusable.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try and show a few URL's I suppose, especially since we don't have the input data to run your application. Depending on the sensitivity, you might want to consider replacing your private key with a test key though.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you have done works as intended, up to the actual request.

`$url = ("https://snapshot.apple-mapkit.com" . $data . "&signature=" . base64_encode($signature));`

Should be:

`$url = ("https://snapshot.apple-mapkit.com" . $data . "&signature=" . urlencode(base64_encode($signature)));`

And this is also the reason you were seeing successes only sometimes - characters in the signature weren't transferred before.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but had exactly the same issue. Thank you - I should have spotted that before, but spent the good part of a day wondering why the code would work sometimes and not others.